# resque blocked by worker job

Tags: ruby, redis, resque

I am using redis pub/sub withing resque worker, resque hangs after first job, 
my worker task is of blocking nature. My understanding is resque forks a new thread for each new job.

my worker is as below

```
class SendInvitation
  @queue = :outbound_dialer
  def self.perform(contact_type, contact_no, invitation_audio_file)
    @invitationManager = DRbObject.new_with_uri(DRB_SERVER_URL)

    task_id = @invitationManager.send_invitation(contact_type, contact_no, invitation_audio_file)
    puts task_id+"is the currents task id"
    $redis = Redis.new(:timeout=>REDIS_TIMEOUT)
    $redis.subscribe('outbound_dialer') do |on|
      on.message do |channel, msg|
        data = JSON.parse(msg)
        if(data['id'] == task_id)
          puts 'here'
          @invitationManager = nil
          # exit
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

ps -ef result

here thread 5784 is blocking resque tasks, as soon as i kill the current processing task, resque start with next task, and again start waiting after completion of that
root 3595 1 0 14:14 ? 00:00:34 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/resque-web
root 5370 1887 0 15:40 pts/1 00:00:04 resque-2.0.0.pre.1: Forked 5784 at 1363947580
root 5784 5370 0 15:49 pts/1 00:00:00 resque-2.0.0.pre.1: Processing outbound_dialer since 1363947580 [SendInvitation]
root 5803 2140 0 15:49 pts/2 00:00:00 grep --color=auto resque

I have already tried COUNT=5

Answer (score 0):

Resque indeed forks a new process (not thread) for a job. It then waits for the worker to finish and grabs the next job. If you want more jobs running in parallel - run more resque worker processes.

Comment: so what does count=5 supposed to do.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: K my exact requirement is to handle asynchronous jobs. I wish to run them as soon as they enqueue. I integrated resqueue just so I can efficiently handle failed jobs. So am I using the right tool or i should be looking something else.

Comment: resque is async, alright. But what should happen if too many jobs are placed to the queue?

Comment: My worker are making sip calls thru soft-pbx, so execution time of each worker would be 2-3 minutes. would it be a nice strategy to Use a fairly large number of workers, say about 200(channel capacity of my pstn line)

Comment: Yes, if your hardware can support 200 concurrently running workers.

Comment: Sidekiq may be a better fit to handle many concurrent jobs. It's multi-threaded, so would use far less memory. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq